# How do I delete a object from inside the class that it uses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, oop

I'm trying to make a contacts app using classes in Python to get familiar with OOP. I want to have a function `delete()` inside the `Contact` class which deletes the object (sets the object/variable to `None`)

The code:

```
class Contact():
    def __init__(self, name, number, contact):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.contact = contact
    
    def delete(self):
        # delete object a
        return
    

a = Contact("test", 5358938, "a@gmail.com")
a.remove()
# a should now be None
```

Comment: Python does not usually have the concept of deleting things. They are normally just forgotten about and python cleans up after you. Anyway, why would you want to change the attributes of a `Contact` if you don't need it anymore? Please update your code with an example of when you don't need `a` anymore.

Comment: If you want to delete an instance, you have to do it outside the Class. I don't think you can delete the instance within its class.

Comment: @quamrana I plan on implementing a feature where if the user clicks a button, it deletes object a. This example is just testing and in the future I will probably use lists to store classes and not variables so the user can have many contacts

Comment: Well, there's your answer. If a variable is stored in a list, then you just drop it from the list and you're done.

Comment: Just use `del obj` instead of `obj.Remove()`>

Comment: you can also try dictionary store all information as key and value and in remove just write the deque.dictionary_name and print the dictionary with rest values import deque from collection and you can also use the lsit and operation for that is pop

Comment: Please read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have at least two classes here; one is the item itself and then a data container to hold the item that has the features for a collection of those items.

(And that container *could* be a Python container so you would add to or delete using that container's methods...)

As a simple example, suppose you want to have a list of names and numbers which is what you consider to be a Contact.

First you need to define a `Contact` and exactly what that is:

```
class Contact:
    # This is for an individual contact
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        
    def __str__(self):
        # this defines how a Contact is converted to a string
        return ','.join(e for e in (self.name, self.number))

    # commonly you would add a way to sort a contact
```

This object is easily extended by adding other fields. All you need to do with `Contact` is:

1. Define what a contact is;
2. perhaps how to print one;
3. perhaps how to sort one.

That is it for now for a Contact. But there may be more types of items such as one for an individual Contact, another for a Company, another for a Professional, etc...)

Now think about having a managed list of these contacts. Now you need to define a class that is a list of Contacts and if there are any special properties to that list:

```
class ContactList:     
    def __init__(self, *contacts):
        self.contacts=[e for e in contacts]
        
    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(str(e) for e in self.contacts)
    
    def remove(self, name):
        self.contacts=[e for e in self.contacts if e.name!=name]
        
    def add(self, contact):
        self.contacts.append(contact)
```

Now you have enough functionality for a phone list:

```
contacts=ContactList(Contact('bob','x34'), Contact('alice','x25'))
print(contacts)
bob,x34
alice,x25

contacts.remove('alice')
print(contacts)
bob,x34

contacts.add(Contact('ted', 'x67'))
print(contacts)
bob,x34
ted,x67
```

In the ContactList class, you might have functionality to do these functions:

1. Create a new list of Contacts;
2. Add or delete contacts;
3. Merge contacts;
4. Print or sort the contact list;
5. Get an individual contact;
6. Query the contacts (everyone who lives in Miami...);
7. Save the contact list to a file or read one from a file;
8. Merge contact lists together;
9. etc etc etc.

Answer (score -1):

as you can see in remove method I have added dictionary and then added with key name and value number you can add Email also after that just delete the key and you all values are deleted

```
class Contact():
def __init__(self, name, number, contact):
    self.name = name
    self.number = number
    self.contact = contact
    
def remove(self,name):
    a={}
    a[name] = self.number
    print(a)
    del a[name]
    print(a)


a = Contact("test", 5358938, "a@gmail.com")
a.remove("test")
```

[image: as you can see first dictionary has object after that del method called and all data removed]